# div a in div b, the background color of div a not affect on all div b

Tags: html, css

i have this html code:

```
    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="leftcol ">
                <h3>When you see a puzzle</h3>
                <div class="image">
                    <img alt="img" src="images/sreak1.jpg" width=75% height=75%>
                        <h3>It scares me </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="image">
                    <img alt="img" src="images/panda1.jpg" width=75% height=75%>
                    <h3>I have to sove it</h3>
                </div>  
                <div class="image">
                    <img alt="img" src="images/sreak2.jpg" width=75% height=75%>
                    <h3>I consult with my friends</h3>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
```

while i define background to "leftcol", there place in "col-2" that the background don't cover (for some reason "col-2" is bigger than "leftcol", and under "leftcol" there still have a place that is "col-2", but not "leftcol") .
how can i solve it?
adding my css code :

```
*{
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;


}
.leftcol{
background-color:rgb(260,60,30);
}
.col-2{
width:16.66%;
}
```

Comment: what in english please?

Comment: Please post your CSS.  If you have floated elements, that could be the source of the issue.

Comment: It would help to see the css file for this as well. My best guess from the information here is that there could be some conflicting styles between the divs or there is some sort of default sizing/padding on the containing "col-2" div that you aren't accounting for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i need to do is to define

```
 <div class="col-2 leftcol ">...
</div>
```

instead of doing it in 2 different divs.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be having some margin or padding
   try this.

```
.col-2{
  padding:0;
}
.leftcol{
      margin:0;
      height:100%;
      width:100%
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code in your css file at the top.

```
*{
   padding:0px;
   margin:0px;
 }
```

Each browsers have their different default padding and margins. So using it will reset all the browser defaults and hopefully everything will work correctly.

Comment: I think you meant `*{...` (the universal selector), but that's a pretty heavy handed method. Better to use a reset style sheet like [normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

Comment: normalize does the same thing and it is always good to use normalize.css when starting a new project.